# When there are few items in listview What's on the right corner right of header column?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, scrollviewer

What's on the right corner When show few item in listview How to change color? I'm not found. But when show more item with scrollbar it normal.

This image for listview problem when few item

[image]

This image for listview not problem when item more

[image]

```
Listview
Background="{x:Null}
BorderBrush="{x:Null}

ListView.ItemContainerStyle
Background="Transparent"
BorderBrush="Transparent"
```

Comment: Try setting `BorderThickness="0"`

Comment: I already setting still having problems

Comment: So the scrollbar for the `ListView` is not behaving correctly. What's your xaml? How do you style your list view?

Answer (score 0):

The default `ControlTemplate` of the `ListView` contains a Border with `Padding` of 2X. Hence you have to change its template something like this

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```